# Why doesn't my BTLE virtual beacon show in Chrome?

Tags: android, google-chrome, bluetooth, ibeacon-android, eddystone

I have a virtual BTLE beacon, created using android-beacon-library. The beacon transmits eddystone-URL frames, containing a https link to goo.gl, which redirects to a twitter https link. It advertises at the maximum power and frequency, and is visible from BeaconToy as valid, however it triggers the Android physical web notification when other nearby phones are unlocked one time in 50, or so. I've tested on 4 phones.

I've tried running the beacon in busy public places and it has never had a clickthrough, which I think is weak evidence that it isn't working for others too.

What should I look at for debugging next? Does Chrome have an option to log beacons?

Comment: Wow, one time in 50 is really really low!  But to confirm, you are saying you consistently see the advertisement just fine when you scan for it manually?

Comment: That's right, I see it showing up as in the immediate vicinity in BeaconToy, with the last seen time reliably increasing every second.